# Wrong element output in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I apologize in advance, but I'm fairly new to C# in this context (I've used it in Unity, but never on its own).

I'm trying to create a string array, and within a loop, have another array with, let's say, a rating system (int elements).
Unfortunately, my problem seems on a level of its own.

This is the code:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string [] arr1 = new string[] {"a","b","c","d","e"};
    int a = 0;
    foreach (var element in arr1)
    {          
        int [] myRate = new int [5] {1,2,3,4,5};
        int [] rating = myRate;
        a = rating[0];
        Console.WriteLine (element +": " + (rating[a]));
    } a++;
  }
}
```

My problem is the output is supposed to be 1 (for all elements because I'm still working on the incrementation), but this is the output:

```
a: 2
b: 2
c: 2
d: 2
e: 2
```

I tried to reduce the code as much as possible to pinpoint the problem (that's why it's kind of minimalistic), but I still cannot figure it out. When I change the zero to 1 the output is 2, and so on. If I change it to 4 it says its out of bound.
Your help is much appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Comment out `a = rating[0];`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, when do this:

```
a = rating[0];
```

then `a` becomes 1, because it's the first item in your `int` array. Then you write this to console:

```
rating[a]
```

...which results to this (since `a` is 1):

```
rating[1]
```

...and the second item in your array is 2, that's why you get this output.

---

Two ways of outputting 1:

```
foreach (var element in arr1)
{          
    int [] myRate = new int [5] {1,2,3,4,5};
    int [] rating = myRate;
    a = 0;
    Console.WriteLine (element +": " + (rating[a]));
} a++;
```

and

```
foreach (var element in arr1)
{          
    int [] myRate = new int [5] {1,2,3,4,5};
    int [] rating = myRate;
    Console.WriteLine (element +": " + (rating[0]));
} a++;
```

---

As a side note, you may consider creating the `int[]` outside your loop, since you are every iteration creating the same array, unless you actually intend to create arrays with different values every new iteration.

Comment: I've tried to initialize a with a zero but the problem persisted. Any recommendations?

Comment: @Freakofif it's very simple. I edited my answer with two options, pick one which best fits your needs. Your logic here seems a bit confusede, but since you reduced the code and told us you are still working on it, I didn't change much in the code.

Comment: I'm sorry I just understood the problem you're describing. So the problem is with how I used the index of the element, correct? How can I fix it?

Comment: @Freakofif if you need the output to be 1, since 1 is the first item within the array, you need to use something like `rating[0]`, because zero will be the first item in your array. So you either use `rating[0]` directly, or make sure `a = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Because "a" contains number "1".

And number 1 on index of rating array is 2.

If you want to print number 1, you should start at index 0. Which is:

```
Console.WriteLine (element +": " + (rating[0]));
```

Comment: Actually, I want to print 1.

Comment: See my answer.. if you want to print 1 use a or rating[0] instead of rating[a].

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help! @Freakofif :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1 in answer then write:

```
Console.WriteLine (element +": " + a);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine (element +": " + rating[0]);
```

because `a=rating[0];` i.e. first element of array whose value is 1.

you are using:

```
Console.WriteLine (element +": " + (rating[a]));
```

i.e. `rating[1]` because value of `a is 1`.

so `rating[1]` is second element of array whose value is `2`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: you only need to change 1 line